# CSS image misaligned

Tags: css, image, alignment, positioning

I'm somewhat new to web design. I've got a webpage with two main sections - text with a logo, and centered image below.

To make logo float with the first section text, I've added `float: left; margin: 4px;` style to the image.

The next image was centered before (there's a "centered" style in the template).
But now it's wrongly aligned with position of above section text instead of page center. While this bug occurs in IE, Firefox is fine. 
How to make it align properly?

The page code is:

```
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Product Logo" style="float: left; margin: 4px;"/>

    <p>All you need to make it work is to install the software and run it. The result will appear automatically!</p>

    <img class="centered" src="screenshots/screenshot_small.png" alt="Product Screenshot" title="Product Screenshot" style="text-align:center;" />
    <p class="caption">Product Screenshot</p>
```

The "Centered" class is defined as follows:

```
img.centered {
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: post your css/html to pastebin.com and provide us a snapshot of your page. it is hard to see what's going on from your description.

Comment: can you give us your current html and css? even better create a demo at http://www.jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you give sources? It's a bit of a crystal ball game otherwise.

Comment: Just updated the question with page and relevant CSS code.

Comment: Do you have Absolute URL's to the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "margin-top:150px" to the second image solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is your image an `img` element? If so, I think you should add `display: block` to it as well to make the floating work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had lots of problems with CSS and aligning things.

First off, use em or % instead of px, they're scalable (for people using cell phones and the like). At 100% zoom, about 1 em = 16 px.

I usually center things by using 2 divs like so:

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:50%; left:50%;">
<div style="position:absolute; width:50%; left:-50%;">
    <!-- Image here -->
</div></div>
```

I personally think it looks ugly, but it works in every browser I've tested it with.

If you need to tweak the position, just play with the values a little.